# Should "Roosevelt was re-elected the President" have "the" and "as"?

Tags: conjunctions, definite-article, proper-nouns

> "Roosevelt was re-elected the President of the United States for the fourth time."

I wonder why "*the United States*" should get rid of "*the*?"

And is it necessary to add "*as*" behind "*re-elected*"？

Comment: Using "as" will never be wrong, but it can be omitted and fluent readers will understand it. It depends on the target audience which way is best.

Comment: The sentence has a semantic error.  FDR was re-elected three times.  He served three full terms, and part of a fourth term.

Comment: In my opinion, "relected" with "as" improves it slightly: "re-elected as the President".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence is correct. You must keep "the" with United States. You do not need to add "as," although you could use it.

Comment: On the other hand, using the definite article before the word "president" is optional here. You can safely use either "Roosevelt was re-elected the President of the United States" or "Roosevelet was re-elected President of the United States." In fact, the latter usage is probably much more frequent nowadays within the United States.